# Error when accessing protected pages : MalformedURLException: "org.osgi.framework.AdminPermission"

Tags: jsf-2, glassfish, osgi, jaas

Whenever I access a protected page on my production server (Glassfish 3.1.2.2 on Debian), I get the followin error :

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: access denied ("org.osgi.framework.AdminPermission" "(id=222)" "resolve,resource")
```

Accoring to the server log (see below), the error is about a denied access but my login script (using JAAS) is working fine.

```
[#|2013-06-15T09:25:49.362-0400|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=86;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|START OF PHASE RESTORE_VIEW 1|#]

[#|2013-06-15T09:25:49.368-0400|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.security|_ThreadID=86;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|JACC Policy Provider:Failed Permission Check: context (" BFjsf/BFjsf ") , permission (" ("org.osgi.framework.AdminPermission" "(id=222)" "resolve,resource") ") |#]

[#|2013-06-15T09:25:49.371-0400|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=86;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|END OF PHASE RESTORE_VIEW 1|#]

[#|2013-06-15T09:25:49.374-0400|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=86;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception

java.net.MalformedURLException: access denied ("org.osgi.framework.AdminPermission" "(id=222)" "resolve,resource")
at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:619)
at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:482)
```

What amazes me is that the error doesn't occur on my development setup (Windows + Netbeans 7.3) but only on the online server, wich has a valid SSL certificate.

The problem occurs whenever I try to access a protected page with a  security constraint, or, in other words when the address displayed in the browser is under the /pages/...  directory (the address displayed by JSF is always a page behind)

eg https://labottedefoin.org/BFjsf/pages/membres/Lister.xhtml?cid=1

as defined in the security constraints of the web.xml file :

```
   <security-constraint>
        <display-name>Authentification</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>pages securisees</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/pages/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>usagers_actifs</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <security-constraint>
        <display-name>Accueil securise</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>accueil securise</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/accueil_secure.xhtml</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <realm-name>BF_realm_config</realm-name>
    </login-config>
    <security-role>
        <description>Rôle correspondant aux usagers ayant «membres_actifs» dans la colonne «groupes» de la table «membres_jaas_authen»</description>
        <role-name>usagers_actifs</role-name>
    </security-role>
```

I have checked that the ~/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/server.policy contains (by default) the authorization for osgi modules :

```
// Felix classes get all permissions by default
grant codeBase "file:${com.sun.aas.installRoot}/osgi/felix/bin/-" {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

I have tried to add the required permission (as follows) but it didn't hep :

```
// Felix classes get all permissions by default
grant codeBase "file:${com.sun.aas.installRoot}/osgi/felix/bin/-" {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
    permission org.osgi.framework.AdminPermission "(id=222)", "resolve,resource";
};
```

Maybe the permission wasn't granted in the right section or in the right file.

Does anybody knows how to solve this problem?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved my problem by adding the permission in the general java.policy file.

I.e., I added the following line :

```
permission org.osgi.framework.AdminPermission "(id=222)", "resolve,resource";
```

at the end of the file

/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_21/jre/lib/security/java.policy